# Displaying Account Details in Table form using AngularJs

Tags: visualforce, javascript-remoting, angularjs

Can anyone tell me how to display Table form for  the account name and account id in visualforce page using AngularJs?
I have created the Visualforce for this use case.
But I didnt get Account details in table form.
My VFP code as follows

```
<apex:page standardStylesheets="false" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" controller="TableFormatContr">   
<html>  

  <head>   

    <script type="text/javascript" src="{!URLFOR($Resource.newformvalidation,'/newformvalidation/angular.js')}"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/angular.ngtable/0.3.3/ng-table.js"></script>

    <link href="{!URLFOR($Resource.newformvalidation,'/newformvalidation/bootstrap.css')}" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/angular.ngtable/0.3.3/ng-table.css"></script>


    <script >
        var app = angular.module('main', ['ngTable']).
            controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope, ngTableParams) {

           var data=[];

                Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
                            '{!$RemoteAction.TableFormatContr.getAccount}',

                            function(result, event){
                                if (event.status) {
                                //Result contains list of account names and account id
                                   data=result;
                                   alert(data.length);
                                   alert("First Account Name:"+data[0].Name);//It display the first account name
                                } else if (event.type === 'exception') 
                                    alert(event.message);

                            }, 
                            {escape: true}
                        );



       $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
            page: 1,            // show first page
            count: 10           // count per page
            }, {
                  total: data.length, // length of data
                  getData: function($defer, params) {
                      $defer.resolve(data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
                  }
               }
       );



});

    </script>
</head>

<body id="body1" ng-app="main" ng-controller="DemoCtrl" onload="getContact()">


    <table ng-table="tableParams" template-pagination="custom/pager" class="table">
        <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
            <td data-title="'Id'">
                {{user.Id}}
            </td>
            <td data-title="'Name'">
                {{user.Name}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="custom/pager">
        <ul class="pager ng-cloak">
          <li ng-repeat="page in pages"
                ng-class="{'disabled': !page.active, 'previous': page.type == 'prev', 'next': page.type == 'next'}"
                ng-show="page.type == 'prev' || page.type == 'next'" ng-switch="page.type">
            <a ng-switch-when="prev" ng-click="params.page(page.number)" href="">&laquo; Previous</a>
            <a ng-switch-when="next" ng-click="params.page(page.number)" href="">Next &raquo;</a>
          </li>
            <li> 

            </li>
        </ul>
    </script>

</body>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
global with sharing class TableFormatContr {

    public TableFormatContr(){}

    @RemoteAction
    global static List<Account> getAccount () {

        List<Account> accList=[select Id,Name from Account];
        return accList;

    }
}
```

The Above Code Doesn't provide  the Account Details in Table form?
I dono whats wrong my code?
Please someone help on this.

Thanks in advance
​Karthick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will produce the table:

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('main', ['ngTable'])
app.controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope, ngTableParams) {
    var data = [];
    Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
       '{!$RemoteAction. TableFormatContr.getAccount}',
       function(result, event) {
            if (event.status) {
                data = result;
                $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
                    page: 1,            // show first page
                    count: 10           // count per page
                }, {
                    total: data.length, // length of data
                    getData: function($defer, params) {
                        $defer.resolve(data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
                    }
                });
                $scope.$apply();
            } else if (event.type === 'exception') {
                alert(event.message);
            }
        }, 
        {escape: true}
    );
});
</script>
```

A key point about this sort of JavaScript is that data is returned to the browser asynchronously by code such as `Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction`. That means that you cannot rely on any values until its callback function - the second argument - has executed. The easiest way to ensure that the values you need are available is to **put the logic that needs the data in the callback function**. (There are probably more elegant patterns but this is a pragmatic fix for your code.)

In many cases Angular can automatically notice changes to values in the scope and render the view accordingly. For cases where it can't, there is [$scope.$apply()](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-$scope.$apply()) to tell Angular to do the render and that appears necessary in this case.

I strongly recommend that if you are going to use Angular that you invest time in learning more about it. I found the https://egghead.io/ videos very helpful for that - they cover key topics in 5 minutes or less.